# what's the meaning of format Z(19)9 in teradata?

Tags: teradata

i see a sql including "format Z(19)9" in terdata environment, and i checked in teradata doc,

the following is for "Z":

```
Zero‑suppressed decimal digit.

Translates to blank if the digit is zero and preceding digits are also zero.

A FORMAT phrase containing Z characters (including Z(I) and Z(F)), a combination of commas, 
dots, G, or D, and no other formatting characters means “blank when zero.”

For example, ZZZZZ, ZZ.Z, GZ(I)DZ(F), GZZZZZZDZZ and Z,ZZZ.ZZ print only blanks if the number 
is zero.

A Z cannot follow a 9.

Repeated Z characters must appear to the left of any combination of the radix and any 9 
formatting characters.

The characters to the right of the radix cannot be a combination of 9 and Z characters; they 
must be all 9s or all Zs. If they are all Zs, then the characters to the left of the radix 
must also be all Zs.

If a group of repeated Z characters appears in a FORMAT phrase with a group of repeated sign 
characters, the group of Z characters must immediately follow the group of sign characters. 
For example, --ZZZ.
```

and the following is for 9:

```
Decimal digit (no zero suppress).
```

but i am still confused, what's the meaning of format Z(19)9 ? for example, the data is 0000.234, then the result will be .234000000 ?

Comment: Z means leading `' '`, 9 leading `'0'` before the first digit. `Z(19)9` formats an *integer* right aligned in 20 characters. For 0000.234 the result would truncated to `0`

Comment: hen how about 123.123 if we apply Z(19)9 ? "                 123" ? 17 leading blank + 123 ?  9 here means no decimal digits, right ?

Comment: Correct, you need to add a fractional part, e.g. `Z(19)9.9(3)`. Btw, FORMAT is mainly used for loading. For numeric to string in queries I prefer TO_CHAR

Comment: understood, thanks